# PHPExcel Get data fromDatabase and put value into cells

Tags: phpexcel

Need some help...
So, i'm trying to export data from database to excel file.
I'm able to fetch data to database,but when i'm exporting it to excel inside the while loop I only got one record.
Please help.I'm using PHPExcel 1.8.0 libray
Here is my code:

```
    <?php

include('config/config_msdb.php');


 /** Set default timezone (will throw a notice otherwise) */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

 // include PHPExcel
require('lib/PHPExcel.php');

// create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;

// set default font
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');

// set default font size
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);


// create the writer
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");


/**

 * Define currency and number format.

 */

// currency format, € with < 0 being in red color
$currencyFormat = '#,#0.## \€;[Red]-#,#0.## \€';

// number format, with thousands separator and two decimal points.
$numberFormat = '#,#0.##;[Red]-#,#0.##';



// writer already created the first sheet for us, let's get it
$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// rename the sheet
$objSheet->setTitle('YellowCab');



// let's bold and size the header font and write the header
// as you can see, we can specify a range of cells, like here: cells from A1 to A4
$objSheet->getStyle('A2:P2')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);



// write header

$objSheet->getCell('A2')->setValue('Date');
$objSheet->getCell('B2')->setValue('TC Within 30 mins');
$objSheet->getCell('C2')->setValue('Total TC');
$objSheet->getCell('D2')->setValue('%');
$objSheet->getCell('E2')->setValue("Within 15 mins");
$objSheet->getCell('F2')->setValue("Total TC");
$objSheet->getCell('G2')->setValue("%");
$objSheet->getCell('H2')->setValue("Excellent TC");
$objSheet->getCell('I2')->setValue("Total TC");
$objSheet->getCell('J2')->setValue("%");
$objSheet->getCell('K2')->setValue('Good TC');
$objSheet->getCell('L2')->setValue('Total TC');
$objSheet->getCell('M2')->setValue('%');
$objSheet->getCell('N2')->setValue('Poor TC');
$objSheet->getCell('O2')->setValue('Total TC');
$objSheet->getCell('P2')->setValue('%');

 //get record
$query="SELECT pr.TransDate,pr.TC30,pr.Total_TRX1,cast(round(pr.Hitrate,0)     as nvarchar (10))+'%' AS Hitrate ,pr.PDT15,pr.Total_TRX2,cast(round(pr.ProdTime,0) as nvarchar(10))+'%' AS ProdTime,pr.Excellence,pr.Total_TRX4,
            cast(round(pr.ExcelPercent,0) as nvarchar(10))+'' AS ExcelPercent,pr.Good,pr.Total_TRX5,cast(round(pr.GoodPercent,0) as nvarchar(10))+'%' AS GoodPercent,
            pr.Poor,pr.Total_TRX6,cast(round(pr.PoorPercent,0) as nvarchar(10))+'%' AS PoorPercent,lp.area_name FROM part_view AS pr
            LEFT JOIN lp_areas AS lp ON lp.id = pr.StoreID
            WHERE lp.is_delete=0 AND lp.area_status=1 AND lp.id!='43'  ORDER BY pr.TransDate DESC";
$que = mssql_query($query);
$i = '3';
while($row=mssql_fetch_array($que)){

    $transdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row["TransDate"]));
    $tc30=$row["TC30"];
    $totaltrx1=$row["Total_TRX1"];
    $hitrate=$row["Hitrate"];
    $pdt15=$row["PDT15"];
    $totaltrx2=$row["Total_TRX2"];
    $prodtime=$row["ProdTime"];
    $excellence=$row["Excellence"];
    $totaltrx4=$row["Total_TRX4"];
    $excelpercent=$row["ExcelPercent"];
    $good=$row["Good"];
    $totaltrx5=$row["Total_TRX5"];
    $goodpercent=$row["GoodPercent"];
    $poor=$row["Poor"];
    $totaltrx6=$row["Total_TRX6"];
    $poorpercent=$row["PoorPercent"];
    $storename=$row["area_name"];

// we could get this data from database, but here we are writing for simplicity

$objSheet->getCell('A'.$i.'')->setValue($transdate);
$objSheet->getCell('B'.$i.'')->setValue($tc30);
$objSheet->getCell('C'.$i.'')->setValue($totaltrx1);
$objSheet->getCell('D'.$i.'')->setValue($hitrate);
$objSheet->getCell('E'.$i.'')->setValue($pdt15);
$objSheet->getCell('F'.$i.'')->setValue($totaltrx2);
$objSheet->getCell('G'.$i.'')->setValue($prodtime);
$objSheet->getCell('H'.$i.'')->setValue($excellence);
$objSheet->getCell('I'.$i.'')->setValue($totaltrx4);
$objSheet->getCell('J'.$i.'')->setValue($excelpercent);
$objSheet->getCell('K'.$i.'')->setValue($good);
$objSheet->getCell('L'.$i.'')->setValue($totaltrx5);
$objSheet->getCell('M'.$i.'')->setValue($goodpercent);
$objSheet->getCell('N'.$i.'')->setValue($poor);
$objSheet->getCell('O'.$i.'')->setValue($totaltrx6);
$objSheet->getCell('P'.$i.'')->setValue($poorpercent);
$i++;



// autosize the columns
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('N')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('O')->setAutoSize(true);
$objSheet->getColumnDimension('P')->setAutoSize(true);


//Setting the header type
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');

/* If you want to save the file on the server instead of downloading, replace the last 4 lines by 
    $objWriter->save('test.xlsx');
*/

}//end get rows
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Increment `$i` inside your loop

Comment: Hi! I already solved my problem Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update I have successfully exported all data fetched from my database.
So here is my solution:

```
$i = '3';
while($row=mssql_fetch_array($que)){

    $transdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row["TransDate"]));
    $tc30=$row["TC30"];
    $totaltrx1=$row["Total_TRX1"];
    $hitrate=$row["Hitrate"];
    $pdt15=$row["PDT15"];
    $totaltrx2=$row["Total_TRX2"];
    $prodtime=$row["ProdTime"];
    $excellence=$row["Excellence"];
    $totaltrx4=$row["Total_TRX4"];
    $excelpercent=$row["ExcelPercent"];
    $good=$row["Good"];
    $totaltrx5=$row["Total_TRX5"];
    $goodpercent=$row["GoodPercent"];
    $poor=$row["Poor"];
    $totaltrx6=$row["Total_TRX6"];
    $poorpercent=$row["PoorPercent"];
    $storename=$row["area_name"];

    $data[] = array(
                'TransDate'=>$transdate,
                'TC30'=>$tc30,
                'Total_TRX1'=>$totaltrx1,
                'Hitrate'=>$hitrate,
                'PDT15'=>$pdt15,
                'Total_TRX2'=>$totaltrx2,
                'ProdTime'=>$prodtime,
                'Excellent'=>$excellent,
                'Total_TRX4'=>$totaltrx4,
                'ExcelPercent'=>$excelpercent,
                'Good'=>$good,
                'Total_TRX5'=>$totaltrx5,
                'GoodPercent'=>$goodpercent,
                'Poor'=>$poor,
                'Total_TRX6'=>$totaltrx6,
                'PoorPercent'=>$poorpercent
    );
}

$array = stripslashes(json_encode($data));
$json = (object)json_decode($array);


foreach($json AS $datas){
    $objSheet->getCell('A'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->TransDate);
    $objSheet->getCell('B'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->TC30);
    $objSheet->getCell('C'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Total_TRX1);
    $objSheet->getCell('D'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Hitrate);
    $objSheet->getCell('E'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->PDT15);
    $objSheet->getCell('F'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Total_TRX2);
    $objSheet->getCell('G'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->ProdTime);
    $objSheet->getCell('H'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Excellence);
    $objSheet->getCell('I'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Total_TRX4);
    $objSheet->getCell('J'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->ExcelPercent);
    $objSheet->getCell('K'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Good);
    $objSheet->getCell('L'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Total_TRX5);
    $objSheet->getCell('M'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->GoodPercent);
    $objSheet->getCell('N'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Poor);
    $objSheet->getCell('O'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->Total_TRX6);
    $objSheet->getCell('P'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->PoorPercent);



$i++;




}
```

Thanks!